# Could spy satellites be blinded? For example by search lights?

Tags: earth-observation

Assume that Doctor Evil insists on dancing outdoors although he has been forbidden by the UN to do so. And that spy satellites can observe this against Doctor Evil's volition.

Could Doctor Evil keep on dancing outdoors invisibly if he dances right around a search light, or some other light source, pointed towards any spy satellite that passes over him?

*(If you wonder, I'm asking on behalf of someone else.)*

Comment: Sure, have a look to any of the available satellite image sources. In most cities you'll find areas of ~ 100 m² blurred out because of reflected sunlight from a roof or window. Might be more difficult in other parts of the non-visible spectrum.

Answer (score 6):

There have been many reports of spy satellites being "blinded" by lasers over the years.

I do not vouch for the accuracy of any of these reports. As you might imagine, hard data is difficult to come by.

By the Soviet Union: ["Late 1975"](https://books.google.com/books?id=AGecCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA34&lpg=PA34&dq=aviation%20week%20spy%20satellite%20blinded&source=bl&ots=4ljklvLIVw&sig=_1ne1msYtznIsmCh0Yj5pjan1_I&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi557_LgLnWAhUS0mMKHQKiDlAQ6AEIQjAE#v=onepage&q=aviation%20week%20spy%20satellite%20blinded&f=false)

By the US: [1997](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIRACL)

By China: [2006](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/1529864/Beijing-secretly-fires-lasers-to-disable-US-satellites.html)

By Iran: [2011](https://www.csmonitor.com/World/Middle-East/2011/1215/Exclusive-Iran-hijacked-US-drone-says-Iranian-engineer) (search article for "laser burst")

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIRACL perhaps?

Comment: Thanks very much @Giskard42 . Didn't know about that one, adding it to the list.